# Understanding socket io

Tags: socket.io

I'm new to socket.io and I'm looking to understand how to use it and what every function does on the client&server side. I'm looking for an example using socket io with a bar that follow the pointer while clicked in really time. Also if u have some good docs to learn from there it would be helpful, the official website isn't that clear for me.

Comment: There are some examples from this Stack Overflow thread that I found useful starting up with socket.io http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914816/what-is-an-example-of-the-simplest-possible-socket-io-example

Comment: Hi you can find a tutorial on usign socketio with nodejs here. http://programmerblog.net/using-socketio-with-nodejs/